# Delete row from MySQL table when I press button Delete

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to make cancel booking of room for one user who can see all his room booked.
The problem is It shows the booked room for the user, but the delete button did not work correctly.

I have snapshot of my db [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWsCy.jpg) and screenshot [`here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwAFf.jpg).please any help?

Thanks.

Here is my php code for show booking data and the delete part in manage.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'webapp');

global $connection;


$user_id="";
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_ID'])) {
header('Location:  login.php'); 
die();
} else {
    $user_id= $_SESSION['login_ID'];
}


    $secondQueryStmt = "SELECT * FROM `booking` where UserID='".$user_id."'";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, $secondQueryStmt);

    if(isset($_POST['BookingID'])) {
    $boking_id = $_POST['BookingID'];
    if(isset($_POST['delete_id'])){




        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM booking where BookingID= '".$boking_id."'");
    }
}
```

?>
here is my form html in the same page also.

```
<article id="content" style="height:810px; background-color:white">
      <div class="box1">
      <!--content herer-->








                    <table class="wrapper" style="text-align:center">
                    <tr>
                    <th class="track animated fadeInUp">Room</th>
                    <th class="title animated fadeInUp">Quantity</th> 
                    <th class="speaker animated fadeInUp">CheckIn Date</th>
                    <th class="day animated fadeInUp">CheckOut Date </th>
                    <th class="time animated fadeInUp"></th>

                    </tr>
                        <?php while($fetcher = mysqli_fetch_array($query)): ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td><?=$fetcher['Type']?></td>
                        <td><?=$fetcher['Quantity']?></td> 
                        <td><?=$fetcher['CheckInDate']?></td>
                        <td><?=$fetcher['CheckOutDate']?></td>
                        <td><td><form action="manage.php"  method= "post" />
                    <input  type="hidden" name="b_id" value="<?=$fetcher['BookingID'] ?>"/>
                    <input type="button"  class="btnSm hvr-fade lightRed" name="delete_id" value="Cancel Booking"/>
                </form></td></tr>



                 <?php endwhile; ?>




        </table>


        </div>
    </article>
```

Comment: remove the * after the DELETE -> delete from TABLE

Comment: I don't see any opening `<form>`, secondly, you need to delete the data first before selecting t, or it will look like the data is not deleted yet even though it is.

Comment: You should check for errors after executing SQL statements. Also learn about prepared statements.

Comment: i am not sure if the booking id is posted or not @Jens

Comment: Thanks all, It works now.

Comment: This code is wide open to exploitation by a malicious user.  Post a form response with BookingID set to `0' OR 1=1 --` and all rows in the booking table will be deleted.  Queries should never be built by concatenating strings and the booking should be verified as belonging to the logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this statement here,

```
<input  type="hidden" name="b_id" value="<?=$fetcher['BookingID'] ?>"/>
                             ^ you've named it b_id, not BookingID
```

So change

```
$boking_id = $_POST['BookingID'];
```

to

```
$boking_id = $_POST['b_id'];
```

And use `mysqli_affected_rows()` function to check how many rows are affected from this `UPDATE` operation.

Here's the reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

So your code should be like this:

```
// your code

$query = mysqli_query($connection, $secondQueryStmt);

if(isset($_POST['delete_id'])){
    $boking_id = $_POST['b_id'];
    mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM booking where BookingID= '".$boking_id."'");
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection)){
        // success
    }else{
        // failure
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your cooperate. I tried it but same problem the button not working .

Comment: @BkrBaroudi That's because your input `type` is `button`, which prevents the form from being submitted. Change the input `type` to `submit`, like this:  `<input type="submit"  class="btnSm hvr-fade lightRed" name="delete_id" value="Cancel Booking"/>`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now after your notes and some modifications. 
I appreciate your help.

Comment: I WISH I HAD SOME REPETITION TO GIVE YOU THUMP UP.

Comment: @BkrBaroudi Glad I could help. Cheers! :-)

Comment: Cheers! best answer ! :)